# Can I use regular expressions re.sub() with a numpy array or list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, numpy, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a numpy array of entries `dtype=string_`. I would like to use the regular expressions `re` module to replace all excess spaces, `\t` tabs, `\n` tabs.

If I was working with a single string, I would use `re.sub()` as follows:

```
import re

proust = 'If a little     dreaming is dangerous, \t the cure for it is not to dream less but to dream more,. \t\t'

newstring = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", proust)
```

which returns

```
'If a little dreaming is dangerous, the cure for it is not to dream less but to dream more. '
```

To do this in each entry of a numpy array, I should somehow use a for loop.

Something like `for i in numpy_arr:`, but I'm not sure what should follow this soc as to apply `re.sub()` to every numpy array element.

What is the most sensible approach to this problem?

---

EDIT:

My original numpy array or list is a LONG list/array of entries, each entry one sentence like the above. An example of five entries is below:

```
original_list = [ 'to be or     \n\n not to be     that is the question', 
'  to   be or  not to be          that is the question\t ', 
'to   be     or not to       be that is the question', 
'to be or not to be that     is    the question\t ', 
'to be or not to be        that is    \t the question']
```

Comment: I cannot see any array on your code.

Comment: `np.char` has functions that apply string methods to elements of an array. The `string.replace` might be included.

Comment: @PedroLobito It's a numpy array shape (1000,), each with a sentence above like `proust`.

Comment: @hpaulj That's a good point. I wonder how one would do this with `regex` though, numpy array or list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't exactly your `re.sub`, but the effect is the same, if not better:

```
In [109]: oarray
Out[109]: 
array(['to be or     \n\n not to be     that is the question',
       '  to   be or  not to be          that is the question\t ',
       'to   be     or not to       be that is the question',
       'to be or not to be that     is    the question\t ',
       'to be or not to be        that is    \t the question'], 
      dtype='<U55')
In [110]: np.char.join(' ',np.char.split(oarray))Out[110]: 
array(['to be or not to be that is the question',
       'to be or not to be that is the question',
       'to be or not to be that is the question',
       'to be or not to be that is the question',
       'to be or not to be that is the question'], 
      dtype='<U39')
```

It works in this case because `split()` recognizes the same whitespace set of characters as '\s+'.

`np.char.replace` will replace selected characters, but it would have to be applied several times to remove '\n', then '\t' etc.  There is also a `translate`.

Comment: Why better? I think it is actually faster, and you don't have to import `re`. Any other reasons?

Comment: Your `re` expresion doesn't remove the initial space on your second string.